# Why is my app asking to enable unknown source even when it was published to play store and installed from playstore

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I have signed my app with jarsigner although it warns that it is self signed, I published it and it has been approved and it's live but it still asks to enable unknown source after downloading from playstore

Answer (score 0):

Please check on a fresh device on which you did not installed the app previously. It will not behave like this on a fresh device